# Interpreting the time complexity of a program from function

Tags: algorithms, runtime-analysis

$T(n)=5T(n/3)+n^2$ Consider this to be the running time of a program. How could we interpret
then numbers 5 and 3.
My Thoughts:
5 times will mean that the problem is divided into 5 subproblems each of size n/3
and then probably to get the solution to the main problem it required $n^2$ steps

I am not sure if that is a perfect explanation or a better way to explain the $n^2$ addition

Comment: Yes, you can think of the the $5T(n/3)$ as the problem on input size $n$ calling $5$ copies of itself on smaller input sizes of $n/3$. The additional $n^2$ is the additional work that we need to solve the problem of size $n$. For example, in merge-sort, to solve an instance of size $n$, we solve two smaller instances of size $n/2$, and use $O(n)$ time to merge these two sub-problem solutions together. Thus merge-sort has $T(n)=2T(n/2)+O(n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. This could be a problem solved using a divide-and-conquer strategy such that the data set is recursively processed in five subsets, each a third of the data, while the split and the merge phases cost $n^2$ altogether.